# Load PHP array into html as select options

Tags: ajax, json

I am having trouble working the finishing touches out with this. I am still fairly new to ajax and json, but here's what i have so far. I am trying to take an array(s) from a php file and load them into a select dropdown (#input) via ajax/json. I think i'm pretty close, but i'm not sure where i'm messing up. Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script src="../_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

if ($("#numbers").val() == "2") {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login.php',
            data: 'id=testdata',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                var numbers = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
                for (i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
                    $('#input').append("<select>" + numbers[i] + 
"</select>");
                }           
            },

        });
} 

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="main">
            <div id="formwrapper">


        <select id="numbers">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <select id="input"></select>


</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my PHP (login.php)

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: What is happening that you don't expect? Also, it looks like you don't understand AJAX at all.

Answer (score 2):

In your script, you aren't doing anything with the data that is returned from the AJAX call. I suspect that is because you don't understand how AJAX works. I'll try to explain it without going into super deep detail.

When you make an AJAX call to a URL, you are making an HTTP request, just like when you type http://www.google.com into your web browser. In response, the server at the other end of that URL sends you an HTTP response with some data.

In the case of your AJAX, you are requesting the response of `login.php`, which, I will assume, is the PHP you added to your question above. In the `success` function, you get a `result`. That `result` is everything that was output by `login.php`.

So,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#numbers").change(function(e) {
        if ($(this).val() == "2") {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'login.php',
                data: 'id=testdata',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    var numbers = result; //result is equal to your array from the php. You don't put PHP here.
                    $('#input option').remove(); //Remove any existing options.
                    for (i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
                        $('#input').append("<option>" + numbers[i] + "</option>");
                    }           
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

If `login.php` is NOT the PHP you added above, then I'm not going to be able to help you until you tell me what file that is from.

Also, notice that we wrapped the AJAX call into a change event on the `#numbers` select box. That way, when the select box's value changes, it will call this AJAX, and select the numbers.

Thanks for the assist tymeJV.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$("#input").append("<option>" + numbers[i] + "</option>");`

Comment: You're right. I just went with what he had in that block. Fixed now.

Comment: There's also a trailing `,` at the end of the success function :)

Comment: I also suspect that the `if` block is wrong, but I'm not sure what he's attempting to accomplish there.

Comment: I was just looking at that...this code will NEVER run if the default selected option isn't set to 2. I'm assuming OP wants this nested in a `change()` event.

Comment: I concur. I wrapped it in a change() event.

Comment: I want the drop down to populate with the php array as options when '2' is selected. And yes, login.php is the filename that my php is in

Comment: @user1873632 Give this a go, and see if it does what you are looking for. I edited it to remove existing options first so that it won't duplicate them every time the AJAX is called.

Comment: still not working. and php page is exactly like above. I also want to be able to put multiple arrays inside the php and pull them aver with json and ajax to populate the list when other options are selected